# Render a relative haml using guard

Tags: ruby, filesystems, haml, guard

My file structure looks like this:

```
Guardfile

resolution1/menu/page1.haml

resolution1/menu/some_partial.haml

resolution2/...

resolution3/...
```

Now, inside page1.haml I have a line which would render a partial haml inside it (I am not using Rails)

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read("./some_partial.haml")).render
```

It fails with:

```
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./some_partial.haml
```

because my working directory is where the Guardfile lies. A workaround that SHOULD work was this:

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read("#{__dir__}/some_partial.haml")).render
```

or if I'm feeling desperate, even this (to get file absolute path)

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read("#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/some_partial.haml")).render
```

However, this isn't working as I wanted it to. The

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

instead of giving my the absolute path to file (with no regard to working directory), it just gives me absolute path to my working directory.

I can, of course, put a path that would work, but I don't want to include my target resolution in every render.

My *Guardfile*

```
guard :haml, output: '../package/www' do
  watch(/^.+(\.haml)$/)
end
```

I am using Windows, damn my life. Any suggestions? I simply need to get a file from a file within the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by how Guard::Haml handles the templates. [It (currently) does this](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml/blob/v1.1.2/lib/guard/haml.rb#L61-L62):

```
content = File.new(file).read
engine  = ::Haml::Engine.new(content, (options[:haml_options] || {}))
```

It reads the template into a string, and then passes that string to Haml. This means that when Haml sees the string, it has no way of knowing what file it should be associated with.

Haml has a [`:filename` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#filename-instance_method) that allows you to pass the filename to Haml. This allows `__FILE__` and `__dir__` to work correctly, but Guard::Haml doesn’t use it at the moment.

I’ve created a [pull request that adds this feature](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml/pull/31). If you want to try out that code before it is merged and a new release is made (assuming it is accepted), you could use the branch on my repo. To do that, change your `Gemfile` to:

```
gem 'guard-haml', :github => "mattwildig/guard-haml", :branch => 'filename_option'
```

(I think it’s also worth pointing out that this setup won’t automatically rebuild the “parent” file if one of the “child” templates is changed).